# vim non-greedy unexpected behavior

Tags: vim, non-greedy

I'm using vim (version 7.3).

On the following line

`1xAxBx4`

where `A` and `B` can be any alphanumerical character, I want to replace `xBx4` with `foo`. I tried the following substitution command

`:s/x.\{-}x4/foo/`

and get `1foo` instead of what I expected (`1xAfoo`). I can get `1xAfoo` if I use this substitution command

`:s/x[^A]x4/foo/`

but this is too specific and won't be helpful if I want to replace on multiple lines, as "A" could be a different character on each line.

Why the unexpected behavior with `\.{-}`? Or is this exactly what one would expect, but I'm just misunderstanding the syntax?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and great first question! I especially appreciate that you've included all the steps, the expected result, and what you actually got, and topped that off by including the Vim version you're using!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you've correctly used the *non-greedy* `\{-}` quantifier, because there's no consumption before, it still will start matching at the first `x`, and then match as few as possible. Because that works, there's no backtracking.

Now, you need to add a greedy match before your expression, yet do not consume those characters. This can be achieved with `\zs` to let the match only start afterwards:

```
:s/.*\zsx.\{-}x4/foo/
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not the use case for "non-greedy".

`x.\{-}x4` will make sense for example you want to replace:

```
xAAAx4BBBx4CCCx4 -> ######BBBx4CCCx4
```

without the usage of `\{-}` the result would be `######`

if it is known that only one single character between `x` and `x4`,  you just use `x.x4` or if you want to avoid space to be selected, use `x\Sx4`